# Selection of names according to their termination

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select

I would like to select cities in my attribute table according to their suffix. For example: select only cities which end with "ton". How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `select by expression` with this expression:

`if (right ("city", 3) = 'ton', true, false)`

where `city` is the fieldname of the string (input) that you want to search - replace it with the name of your field.

Output of the expression is `true` if the suffix is `ton`, otherwise it is `false` - combined with `select by expression` it will create a selection of cases that end in -ton.

Answer (score 5):

Simply you can use `Like` function in `Select by expression`. Assuming the field name of cities is "CityName" it will be like this:

```
"CityName" LIKE '%ton'
```

In the following example, the field name of city names is `Name`. Applying the above expression

```
"NAME" LIKE '%ton'
```

I got the following result:

[image]